# Error in thermal time constant from measurement

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, thermal-conductivity, electrical-engineering

I would like to know how to calculate the error in thermal time constant ($\tau$) based on temperature measurements. For example, lets say I have a plate with a thermocouple and I provide it with a step input. The step power input will cause a $1$st order temperature change at the location of the thermocouple.

The temperature at time $t$ is
$$
 T(t) = T_s + (T_i - T_s) e^{-t/\tau}.
$$
where $T_s$ the static-state (equilibrium) temperature, $T_i$ the initial temperature.

At $t=\tau$, we have $$T(\tau) = T_s + \frac{T_i - T_s}{e}$$
I can find the temperature at time $\tau$ and from the temperature vs time measurement data I can determine the time constant $\tau$ ($T_i$ and $T_s$ are both not $0 C/K$).

If my thermocouple has a fixed error of lets say $\pm 1 C$, then what would be the error in the derived time constant, $\tau$?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If you didn't know the time constant $\tau$ before measuring, how to find temperature at this unknown time?

Comment: Since I can find the temperature to expect when the time = 1xtime constant (second equation), I can use the temperature vs time graph from measurement to locate when that temperature is reached and read out the time. That time will be my time constant.

Answer (score 0):

From $ T(t) = T_s + (T_i - T_s) e^{-t/\tau}$ you can express $\tau$:
$$
t \rm{ln} \big[\frac {T_i - T_s}{T(t) - T_s}\big]   = \tau.
$$ For *small* errors in temperature measurements you can write this as $t \rm{ln} \big[\frac {T_i +\delta T_i - T_s - \delta T_s}{T(t)+\delta T - T_s-\delta T_s}\big]   = \tau +\delta\tau$ and can expand to first order as
$$\delta \tau/t \approx  \frac {1}{(T_i - T_s)} \delta T_i  
- \frac {1}{T(t) - T_s} \delta T\\
+\big(\frac {1}{T_s - T_i}+\frac{1}{T_s-T(t)}\big) \delta T_s
$$
To a first order with independent (uncorrelated) measurement errors in the quantities $T_i,T_s, T(t)$, the error variance estimate is then
$$\sigma_{\tau}^2 /t^2 \approx  \frac {1}{(T_i - T_s)^2} \delta (T_i)^2 
+ \frac {1}{(T(t) - T_s)^2} (\delta T)^2 
+\big(\frac {1}{T_s - T_i}+\frac{1}{T_s-T(t)}\big)^2 (\delta T_s)^2 $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are a few things I dont understand. How did we get to tln[(Ti+δTi−Ts−δTs)/(T(t)+δT−Ts−δTs)]=τ+δτ? Is this because we assume the errors tend to zero? Also, do we get to the next equation? First order Taylor expansion? Sorry, I'm trying to understand the steps to the final equation.

Comment: Any educational links that will explain your procedure is also appreciated :)